# Cloudera quickstart Docker container not running on Windows 10 Home

Tags: docker, cloudera, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to run the Cloudera docker machine in Windows 10 but it dies before even logging a line, I try

```
docker run -m 8G --memory-reservation 3G --memory-swap 8G --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -v C:\\sw\\mi_docker_vol_1:/src --publish-all=true -p 8888 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

But it is not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that there is a compatibility issue between older docker images and WSL2, and you can not have WSL1 in Windows home, so you need to workaround this issue.

In order to solve it create a file .wslconfig in your user folder as follows:

%userprofile%/.wslconfig

And then copy this:

```
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate
```

Then restart the wsl2 kernel service in Windows services which is called LxssManager and you are ready to go.

[image: docker container running on windows home]

Comment: You saved my day, thank you so much!